# Javascript library independent tooltip

Tags: javascript

can anyone recommend me nice tooltip script which is javascript library independent, meaning no help/code from any of libraries such as (jquery, prototype,scriptalicious, mootools,extjs etc.).

Here is [the one](http://www.beauscott.com/examples/help_balloons/doc/examples.htm) I particularly like but it uses protoype and that is not option for me now, because I'm just integrating something else into already existing huge script and I don't wanna mess up old functionality or bring some additional unnecessary overhead.

Or even better if you can give me some guidelines / pointers , how to make one from scratch that would be acceptable for me also.

The most important thing is that it points from above downwards, because I found like dozen of good ones but pointing from below. Here is an example what I mean when I say from pointing from above.

[image: Here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script that doesn't use any of the libraries you mention. Get it [here](http://www.walterzorn.com/tooltip/tooltip_e.htm). By itself it does not do the arrowed corner like you want but in the description where it says 'Extensions (plugins)' they show you an example of a tool tip like that, all you have to do is include an extension of theirs, called Balloon Tooltip, with the said script. Just follow the links to this extension (I would have linked it but aparently I need 10 rep points to have more than one link in my post). This way you will get a tool tip like this without depending on a library. With this extension you are able to customise the images that get used to make the tooltip as well! :D

Comment: Hmm this looks awesome, I'm looking on click behaviour .. when I change it from onmouseover to onclick it doesn't respond. What I really need is this tooltip to be trigered on some event, fox ex: I have a function which fires when something is selected or when something is dragged, is it possible to add this tooltip to those functions to fire when certain event is triggered.

Comment: You can change the default configuration values inside the library itself (section GLOBAL TOOLTIP CONFIGURATION), or configure each tooltip individually by passing commands to the particular eventhandlers. I haven't played with this script much but perhaps you will need to make changes in both places, globally and locally. Is this how you are doing it already?

onclick="Tip('text')" or onmouseup="Tip('text')"